# Example of Public site with List Filters

Tags: filter, olap, pivot-tables, search

I am looking for an example of public SharePoint site that allows multiple filtering on a list of results.
For example, the visitor should be able to filter a list of announcements, or a list of products, based on a combination of multiple criteria: geography, date, category, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out metanavigation and filtering on standard listview in SharePoint 2010?
It can be enabled if list contains content types with taxonomy or multivalue fields.

Comment: I haven't yet. But right now what I am looking for is a real life example I can point people to.